# XSL:SORT doesn't work?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that contains price value.I want to sort my table in order of price: here is my code but in IE it doesn't work and the value of other elements together show in price tabledata:

```
        <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates >
            <xsl:sort select="price" data-type="number" order="descending" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </td>
```

and my xml file ([book.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

this is my XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="catalog">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
           <xsl:text>Buchhandlung</xsl:text> 
        </title> 
      </head>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>author</th>
          <th>titel</th>
          <th>price</th>
          <th>description</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
  </table>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="book">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@id" />
        </td>

        <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="author" />
        </td>

        <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="title" />
        </td>

        <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="book" >
            <xsl:sort select="price" data-type="number" order="descending"  />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </td>
        <!--<td>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="price" />
        </td>-->

        <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="description" />
        </td>
      </tr>
  </xsl:template>
<
```

/xsl:stylesheet>

Thank you for your helps

Comment: Please post some .xml sample.

Comment: That snippet alone does not tell us much, show us a sample of the input XML, at least a complete template of the XSLT so that we have a context, then the output you want and the one you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort` by itself doesn't produce output. It dictates the order in which the sorted node-set is passed to anything in the current scope - so you'll need to add something like `<xsl:value-of select="price"/>` below it - the value-of instruction will print out the prices in order of size instead of the natural order of the file.

edit #1: I've now noticed you're using it inside `apply-templates` and not `for-each`. In this case, you'll need to define a template that matches a `price` node. This template will then be called on each price node in your sort order, instead of their order in the file.

edit #2: An example; to print a list of book details in order of the price of the book, you'll probably want something like:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="catalog">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
           <xsl:text>Buchhandlung</xsl:text> 
        </title> 
      </head>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>author</th>
          <th>titel</th>
          <th>price</th>
          <th>description</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="book">
          <xsl:sort select="price"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
  </table>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="book">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@id" />
        </td>

        <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="author" />
        </td>

        <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="title" />
        </td>  

        <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="description" />
        </td>
      </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

Notice that the catalog template now contains the sorting logic, and I have removed similar logic from the book template. The book template has no power to sort the nodes passed into it, you have to dictate what order the target nodes are passed to the book template to get the result you're after. The catalog template ensures that each `book` element is passed into `template match="book"` in order of price, not the order in the file. I've assumed that you don't want to print the book price inside the book details since the example you gave wouldn't have done this either, but if you want to include this information it would be done in exactly the same way as the `td` output for the other fields.

Comment: Thank's Tom.Did you mean that i should do this:

Comment: <xsl:template match="price">
    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:sort select="price" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: Not exactly. The snippet you've given still doesn't produce any output. Inside your `<template match="price">` element, you'll want something like `<td><value-of select="."/></td>`. The `"."` selector here assumes that since you're already inside a template that matches a given node name, you should print the value of the current node. All the `sort` element does is modify the order in which the selected nodes are passed to the template.

Comment: Tom I'm new in XML and XSLT .I edited my post .Would you please tell me,what should i do in my code?Thank you very much

Comment: It's not clear exactly what output you want from reading your stylesheet - but I'll try to provide an example based on your markup that I think should do what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

You need code along the lines of

```
<xsl:template match="catalog">
  <table>
    <tbody>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="book">
       <xsl:sort select="price" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
     </xsl:appl-templates>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book/*">
 <td>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </td>
</xsl:template>
```